# Spivak calculus on manifolds 3-34

Tags: calculus

Here is the problem:

> *Let $g_1, g_2$ be continuously differentiable functions such that $D_1 g_2=D_2g_1$, and define $$f(x,y) =
>  \int_0^xg_1(t,0)dt+\int_0^yg_2(x,t)dt.$$ prove $D_1f(x,y) =
>  g(x,y)$.*

What I get is

$ D_1f(x,y)=D_1\int_0^xg_1(t,0)dt + D_1\int_0^yg_2(x,t)dt=\\\int_0^xD_1g_1(t,0)dt + \int_0^yD_1g_2(x,t)dt=\\g_1(x,0) +g_1(x,y).$

but $g_1(x,0) \not=0$ in simple examples.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: $D_1$ refers to the partial w.r.t. $x$ for $f$. Do you see the problem now?

Comment: a little subtlety: if instead the second term was $\int_0^y g_1(t,x)dt$, then $D_1\int_0^y g_1(t,x)dt = \int_0^y D_2g_1(t,x)dt$. Notice how the 1 became a 2 even though the variable had not changed yet.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Good point, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will write out the full proof here:

$$D_1 f(x,y) = D_1 \int_0^x g_1(t,0)dt + D_1\int_0^y g_2(x,t)dt = g_1(x,0) + \int_0^y D_1g_2(x,t)dt$$

$$= g_1(x,0) + \int_0^y D_2g_1(x,t)dt = g_1(x,0) + g_1(x,y) - g_1(x,0) = g_1(x,y)$$